# Can a null graph be considered k-regular, for any k ?

Tags: graph-theory

By null graph I mean a graph without any vertices. I did not find any mention of this anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the definition of a k-regular graph it's obvious taht you can consider the empty graph k-regular for any k. Why? Because since it has no vertices the statement: "every vertex has degree k" is true for any k.

But I am not sure how that helps and in what scenarios.

Comment: I would say the null graph is regular but never $k$-regular as it has no vertices of degree $k$.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Yes, that interpretation is also possible. It's maybe better even.

Comment: The definition I am using is regular means every vertex has the same degree but $k$-regular means a regular graph with vertices of degree $k$... so it depends on the definition.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy Right, I agree. Depends on the exact wording. But again, k-regular or not, I am not sure of what use it is to consider the empty graph.

Comment: @Nico Depends how exactly you define k-regular. If the definition implies it has at least one vertex (which is of course of degree k) then the empty graph is not k-regular.

Comment: Yeah. Deleted my previous comment instead of editing it, but I agree with that. I know it's rather silly but it was bugging me. Thanks guys!